# ifelse statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am inside a user generated function in R and want some lines of code to be conditioned on the parameters. For example, `Position` is an input for the function. I want to display or not display an axis if this variable is 2 or 4. This is what I have but it doesn't seem to work. Is something like this possible in R? (see line 2 of the code)

```
Themes <- theme(axis.title = element_text(size=fsizes),
                  if(Position == 2 | Position == 4, axis.text.x=element_blank() , axis.text.x = element_text(size=fsizes, color = "black")), 
                  axis.text.y = element_text(size=fsizes, color = "black"), 
                  title=element_text(size=fsizes), 
                  legend.text=element_text(size=fsizes-1.5),
                  legend.key.width = unit(.1, "cm"), legend.key.height = unit(.2, "cm"),
                  legend.position = "top",
                  legend.direction = "horizontal",
                  legend.margin = unit(0, 'cm'),
                  axis.ticks = element_line(size = .2),
                  panel.grid.major = element_line(size=.2),
                  panel.grid.minor = element_line(size=.1),
                  plot.margin = unit(c(.1,.1,.1,0), 'cm')
                  )
```

Comment: Did you look at `help(ifelse)` ?

Comment: Yes, but that did not seem to help me in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `` `if` `` is what you are after here. Write `` ?`if` `` for help, but the idea is:

```
if(condition) expression
```

or as in this case:

```
if(condition) {
  expression 1
} else {
expression 2
}


ifelse(test, cond1, cond2)
```

i believe is not used much to test simple conditions in functions.
of course take a look at `?ifelse` anyway.

```
require(ggplot2)


theme_fun <- function(Position = NULL, fsizes = NULL){
  theme = theme(axis.title = element_text(size=fsizes), 
                 axis.text.y = element_text(size=fsizes, color = "black"), 
                 title=element_text(size=fsizes), 
                 legend.text=element_text(size=fsizes-1.5),
                 legend.key.width = unit(.1, "cm"), legend.key.height = unit(.2, "cm"),
                 legend.position = "top",
                 legend.direction = "horizontal",
                 legend.margin = unit(0, 'cm'),
                 axis.ticks = element_line(size = .2),
                 panel.grid.major = element_line(size=.2),
                 panel.grid.minor = element_line(size=.1),
                 plot.margin = unit(c(.1,.1,.1,0), 'cm')
  )

  if(Position == 2 | Position == 4){
    theme = theme + axis.text.x=element_blank()
  } else {
    theme = theme + axis.text.x = element_text(size=fsizes, color = "black")
  }
}
```

**EDIT to clarify the comments**

```
x = "hello"

# This if else construct
if(x == "hello"){
  print("como va che?")
} else {
  "hello"
}

# Is equivalent to this
`if`(x == "hello", "como va che?", "hello")
```

The point of the comment is to clarify that `function` is another way to access a function.
For example, if you would like to read the help.

```
?`if`
```

Here is another example:

```
`+`(1, 100)
```

Comment: Thank you! updated just a couple bugs. Needed to add the theme() back into the if else statements

Comment: Great! But please take note that `if` and ```ifelse()``` are two different functions.

Comment: I see that now. I'm used to programming in SAS, so I'm still learning the differences in programming styles.

Comment: @Hong Ooi The way to address functions in R such as if, and for is the following: if , for. This is not an error in the answer, just to clarify for the edit attemp to erase these characters!!!

Comment: @MartínBel, I'm confused by both your edit reversals and your comments.  What were you trying to accomplish (or reverse)?  And which characters are you concerned about?  Right now for the answer shows ?[quote]if[quote] (where quote is the single backquote), which doesn't work; simply `?if` does.

Comment: ?if doesn't work, you need the quote function quote syntax. Please read hadley's book, he explains it much better than i do. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#every-operation-is-a-function-call

Comment: Markdown is stupid, but note that `?"if"` also works.

Comment: Interesting!  `?if` works here, as does `?"if"` and `?'if'`, but not `?[quote]if[quote]`, as in the current version of the answer.

Comment: when printing ?if in the command line i get +. Meaning it's not getting me the help files. I'm using R 3.02, windows 64. It's hard with markdown, but [back-quote]if[back-quote] is actually the function name. The other quotes work because the names are matched, but are not really the name of the function. When i print: ```> `if`
#I get the following: > .Primitive("if")```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to replace your second line of code:

```
if(Position == 2 | Position == 4, 
   axis.text.x=element_blank() , 
   axis.text.x = element_text(size=fsizes, color = "black")),
```

with this:

```
axis.text.x= ifelse(Position==2 | Position==4, 
                    element_blank(), 
                    element_text(size=fsizes, color = "black")),
```

Comment: @jilhoward I like this solution. It seems interesting for a function.